# About a sequence of holomorphic maps from annuli

Tags: cv.complex-variables, limits-and-convergence

Let $A_n=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: \epsilon_n\leq |z| \leq 1\}$ and
$$
f_n\colon A_n\to \mathbb{C}, \quad n\in \mathbb{N},
$$ 
be a sequence of holomorphic functions such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \epsilon_n=0$, and for any $r<1$, 
$\{f_n|_{\{z\in \mathbb{C}: r\leq |z| \leq 1\}}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$  converges to $0$ in $C^\infty$-norm (Uniformly with all derivatives).

Is it true that either $\lim_{n\to \infty} ||f_n(x)||_{\infty} =0$ for all $x$ or (after passing to a subsequence) there are sequences of points $\{z_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $\{w_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ in the boundary components $\{|z|=\epsilon_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ with 
$$
\Big(\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(z_n) \neq  \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(w_n) \Big) \in \mathbb{C}\cup \{+\infty\} \cup \{-\infty\}.
$$

Comment: What is the meaning of $\lim_{a\to\infty}f_a\to 0$?

Comment: This  remind  me  a  problem  in  complex  analysis  of  Ahlfors which  states that the  uniform limit  of  a  sequence  of  injective  holomorphic  functions  is  either injective or  constant. May  be  some  strategies  of the  solution of that problem could  be useful in this  question.

Comment: I saw  this  problem in Ahlforse  book about  20 years  ago.

Comment: The injective case should be easy. You can argue geometrically then.

Comment: @MohammadF.Tehrani  The  injective  case is  an immediate  consequence of  the  following  lemma: Lemma:"If $f_n \to  f $ uniformly on compact  sets  and  $f$ is  not  a constant  with  f(a)=0 for  some  $a$ then there is a sequence $a_n \to a$  with  $f_n(a_n)=0$"  Proof: Choose  a  small circle $C_{\epsilon}$  around $a$ then $\int_{C_{\epsilon}}  \frac{f_n'}{f_n} \to  \int_{C_{\epsilon}}  \frac{f'}{f} $  but these integrals  count the  number of  zeros inside  $C_{\epsilon}$.  This  lemma  obviously proves  the  injectivity. Now  I guess that (perhaps) the  same  strategy works in the

Comment: case of your question.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that I understand your question correctly. In particular, I am not sure what $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ mean.

As I first understood it, the answer is negative. Let $A(r,1)$ be the annulus of points with  $r<z<1$.

Define $\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}\eps_n := 1/n^2$, $A_n := A(\eps_n,1)$ 
and set 
$f_n\colon A_n \to \mathbb{C}; z\mapsto \frac{1}{nz}$.

Then clearly the functions converge uniformly to zero on every annulus $A(\eps,1)$. However, if $z_n$ is any sequence with $|z_n|=\eps_n$, then 
$$ |f_n(z_n)| = n \to \infty.$$

However, if by converging to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$, you mean that points should converge to infinity along different rays (e.g. asymptotically to the positive/negative real axis), I think the answer is positive.

Indeed, the maximum must be taken on the boundary, and because the function has no poles and takes values near zero, the image of the boundary cannot be contained in a small neighbourhood of some finite value. So, either you can find subsequences of values converging to finite values, or, for large $n$, the image of the boundary surrounds any fixed disc around the origin. In the latter case, it must contain arbitrarily large positive and negative real values.